# Object needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-related-manager

I have the following code in my **models.py**:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)

class Article(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for tag in self.tags:
            print tag.name
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I try to create an article from the admin panel, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: "<Article>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

How can I fix this problem? I need to access and iterate the tags **before** saving the article. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the issue is that the tags are only created post save in m2m, so your save method override wouldn't work in the default admin behaviour

Answer (score 3):

Your Declaration of

```
form.save_m2m()
```

should be after

```
obj.save()
```

After saving of object Many to Many field will add

Answer (score 1):

Your models are bellow:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)

class Article(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for tag in self.tags:
            print tag.name
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

when you want to create a Article instance with tags, you should create the instance firstly, then add the `tags`, like bellow:

```
article = Article.objects.create()

tags = [tag_instance1, tag_instance2, tag_instance3 ...]

article.tags.set(tags)
```

or

```
article.tags.add(tag_instance)
```